# Is there a way to Reverse a Rule's logic in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, rules, clause

I understand that the `\+` symbol in Prolog stands for "not provable", which evaluates to false if some clause is provable.

This got me thinking about the reversibility of a Rule's logic, is there a way to reverse a rules logic that uses similar syntax to the `\+` symbol given above? i.e. that doesn't require you changing the clause itself.

By reverse I mean the rule's logic is inverted. For example, if the rule is `X > Y`, then the reverse returns the outcome `X < Y`.

For a more complex example, imagine, instead, I had the clause:

```
passed(X, Y) :- mark(X, Y, Z), Z >= 40.
mark(john, maths, 50).
mark(paul, maths, 10).
mark(harry, maths, 78).
```

Could I reverse the following statement:

```
?- passed(X, maths).
X = john
X = harry
```

So that I get:

```
X = paul
```

Comment: Define "reverse". `\+` has caveats: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715070/prolog-negation-and-logical-negation

Comment: @brebs I added additional information on what I mean by reversing the logic, does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

[Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) is a really complex topic... Prolog offers a practical way to model **some** of its features in the restricted domain it can handle. For your example, use sufficiently instantiated arguments to get a constructive proof:

```
passed(X, Y) :- mark(X, Y, Z), Z >= 40.
mark(john, maths, 50).
mark(paul, maths, 10).
mark(harry, maths, 78).

?- mark(Student,_,_),\+passed(Student,math).
```

Answer (score 1):

Could represent as:

```
mark(john, maths, 50).
mark(paul, maths, 10).
mark(harry, maths, 78).

pass_mark(maths, 40).

% Passed is a Boolean, i.e. true or false
passed_subject_t(Person, Subject, Passed) :-
    mark(Person, Subject, Score),
    pass_mark(Subject, PassMark),
    call_t(Score >= PassMark, Passed).

% Generic predicate
call_t(Goal, Bool) :-
    % Don't use *-> because Goal might contain ";" alternatives
    (   call(Goal)
    ->  Bool = true
    ;   Bool = false
    ).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- findall(P, passed_subject_t(P, maths, true), Ps).
Ps = [john, harry].

?- findall(P, passed_subject_t(P, maths, false), Ps).
Ps = [paul].
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can but it won't be automatic.
Here, you could use a clpfd "reified" constraint.
For example, for SWI, in [the docs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-reification), one can find `#\ Q` predicate.

Example queries:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- X #>= 40.
X in 40..sup.

?- #\ X #>= 40.
X in inf..39.
```