# Solving a logical puzzle with Prolog gives a wrong answer

Tags: prolog

I've got a simple puzzle: We've got 2 people, Zod and Jenk. Each of them is either Truthful and always making true statements, or Lying and always making false statements. Zod says: "We are both truthful". Jenk says: "At lease one of us is lying".

The solution is that Zod is lying and Jenk is truthful.

I'm trying to solve it using Prolog but somehow it comes to a conclusion that both are Truthful. Here's the program:

```
% Define the possible states for each person
state(zod, truthful).
state(zod, lying).
state(jenk, truthful).
state(jenk, lying).

% Zod says: "We are both truthful".
zod_statement :- state(zod, truthful), state(jenk, truthful).

% Jenk says: "At least one of us is lying".
jenk_statement :- state(zod, lying); state(jenk, lying).

% Check if a person's statement is true based on their state
statement(zod) :- 
    state(zod, truthful), zod_statement;
    state(zod, lying), \+ zod_statement.

statement(jenk) :- 
    state(jenk, truthful), jenk_statement;
    state(jenk, lying), \+ jenk_statement.

% The solution must satisfy both statements
solution(ZodState, JenkState) :-
    state(zod, ZodState),
    state(jenk, JenkState),
    statement(zod),
    statement(jenk).
```

If I comment out `state(zod, truthful)` and leave the only possibility for Zod as `lying` it works, but if it's got both options for Zod it comes back with `JenkState = ZodState, ZodState = truthful` which is incorrect.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `\+` does not instantiate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715070/prolog-negation-and-logical-negation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can reify this, so that the person's variable is whether they are telling the truth.

```
truthful(true).
truthful(false).

zod_jenk(Z, J) :-
    person_truthful(zod, Z, J),
    % Only this Jenk rule is actually needed
    person_truthful(jenk, J, Z),
    % Ensuring that Z and J are ground
    truthful(Z),
    truthful(J).

% Zod is telling the truth if Jenk is telling the truth
person_truthful(zod, true, true).
% If Zod is lying, don't know about Jenk
person_truthful(zod, false, _J).

% If Jenk is truthful then Zod must be lying (to be the "at least 1")
person_truthful(jenk, true, false).
% If Jenk is lying, then at least one of them is lying - contradiction
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- zod_jenk(Z, J).
Z = false,
J = true.
```

The Zod rule isn't even needed.